# How uncommon is the phrase "till soon"

Tags: word-usage

I thought the phrase "till soon" was a correct alternative to "see you soon", but after searching online it doesn't seem to be. I've used it quite frequently, so now I'm wondering, how weird will this have sounded to a native speaker?

Comment: Very uncommon and not idiomatic - unless one were employing it for special emphasis, or to get a point across. ("Until Wednesday, er, no Friday, sorry, no - err umm - til soon!  See you soon!)

Comment: @WS2 Thanks, I guess I've sounded like a complete idiot for a long time then, good to know ;). I'll stop using it.

Comment: And apologies for my typo. *Till* has two l's.

Comment: Agreed - I don't believe I've ever heard it used.

Comment: Thanks, I hope the native English speakers of this world are forgiving, one of the many struggles of being a non-native speaker :(...

Comment: I like it. It's a good invention. Till when? Soon.

Comment: I wouldn't worry that you sounded like an idiot—if you haven't been getting a lot of "*Huh?*"s and "*Sorry, what?*"s you were probably understood just fine, and just sounded quaint or cosmopolitan, depending on the attitude of the listener. Salutations can be pretty idiosyncratic, anyway; I know a Latinist who likes to say *Salve!* and an anthropologist who uses *good energy!*.

Comment: Well  natives say *see you later* and *later*, and I suppose *till later* is possible, although I don't use it; as far as *till soon*, it does sound strange, but as @1006a says, people use all kinds of salutations, although many who deviate from the standard ones are considered idiocentric.

Comment: @1006a Haha, thanks for the reassurance. I translated it literally from my native language and always assumed it was right. Just need to remember now to avoid it in the future, but good to hear I hopefully got away with it ;)!

Comment: Thanks @Clare, at least being considered idiocentric isn't as bad as being perceived as a complete idiot ;). I'll remember to avoid it from now on though :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WS2 comments

> Very uncommon and not idiomatic - unless one were employing it for special emphasis, or to get a point across. ("Until Wednesday, er, no Friday, sorry, no - err umm - till  soon! See you soon!")